# Unable to create more than 5 subnets in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, ip, amazon-vpc

I am using terraform module vpc to create a VPC with more than 5 subnets

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.70.0"

  name = "test"
  cidr = "10.6.0.0/16"
  azs  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  public_subnets  = [cidrsubnet("10.6.0.0/16", 8, 0)]
  private_subnets = [for i in range(1, 11): cidrsubnet("10.6.0.0/16", 8, i)]

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  create_igw           = true

  default_security_group_egress = [{
    cidr_blocks = "0.0.0.0/0"
  }]

  default_security_group_ingress = [{
    description = "Allow all internal TCP and UDP"
    self        = true
  }]

  tags = {
    Resource  = "vpc"
    Name      = "test"
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
│ Error: creating EC2 EIP: AddressLimitExceeded: The maximum number of addresses has been reached.
│       status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
│ 
│   with module.vpc.aws_eip.nat[6],
│   on .terraform/modules/vpc/main.tf line 926, in resource "aws_eip" "nat":
│  926: resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
```

I have read that I can create 200 subnets per Availability Zone in a VPC in a Region. But can't make more than 5 when I tried.

Comment: This error is referring to an Elastic IP address (EIP), not a subnet. [Elastic IP address limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-limit) states that only five elastic IP addresses are allowed per account per region.

Comment: It seems to be wanting to create a NAT Gateway in every subnet? You probably don't want one NAT Gateway per private subnet. At most you'd want one per Availability Zone.

Comment: or... you can increase the EIP quota...

Answer (score 3):

The error message you encountered suggests that you have reached the limit for the number of Elastic IP (EIP) addresses that can be created in your AWS account. By default, AWS imposes a soft limit of five EIPs per region for EC2 instances. To create more EIPs, you can request a limit increase from AWS Support.

However, it's important to note that using an EIP for each subnet might not be the most efficient or cost-effective approach. Instead, you can consider using NAT gateways or NAT instances to provide outbound internet access to your private subnets. NAT gateways and instances share EIPs and allow multiple subnets to use the same public IP for outbound connections.

To modify your Terraform configuration, you can update the `enable_nat_gateway` parameter to `false` and remove the `aws_eip` resource block for NAT gateways. This way, you won't encounter the EIP limit issue.

Here's an updated example:

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.70.0"

  name = "test"
  cidr = "10.6.0.0/16"
  azs  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  public_subnets  = [cidrsubnet("10.6.0.0/16", 8, 0)]
  private_subnets = [for i in range(1, 11): cidrsubnet("10.6.0.0/16", 8, i)]

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_nat_gateway   = false
  create_igw           = true

  default_security_group_egress = [{
    cidr_blocks = "0.0.0.0/0"
  }]

  default_security_group_ingress = [{
    description = "Allow all internal TCP and UDP"
    self        = true
  }]

  tags = {
    Resource  = "vpc"
    Name      = "test"
  }
}
```

By disabling the `enable_nat_gateway` parameter and removing the `aws_eip` resource block for NAT gateways, you'll rely on other methods (such as NAT gateways or instances) to provide internet access to your private subnets, and you won't hit the EIP limit.

Remember to consider the costs and requirements of your specific use case when deciding whether to use NAT gateways or NAT instances.

Comment: I need nat gateway. Can I instead request for increase in IP address? Will that work?